# Chromium binary not being found using Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am using Selenium in a MacOS server. I have intsalled bith chrome and chromedriver, but with my code, I get an error saying the binary was not found.

This is the code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
if(env['HEADLESS']):
    options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--auto-show-cursor')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
except WebDriverException:
    # Exception occurred, try using the specified executable_path
    chrome_binary_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
    options.binary_location = chrome_binary_path
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)# I have previously tried driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chrome_binary_path, options=options)
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/src/BL/browsers.py", line 21, in chrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /snap/chromium/2529/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x560c936c76a3 <unknown>
#1 0x560c9340cad6 <unknown>
#2 0x560c934354c6 <unknown>
#3 0x560c934318a0 <unknown>
#4 0x560c9346f78d <unknown>
#5 0x560c9346ef6f <unknown>
#6 0x560c93466993 <unknown>
#7 0x560c9343c414 <unknown>
#8 0x560c9343d47e <unknown>
#9 0x560c9368aacd <unknown>
#10 0x560c9368f505 <unknown>
#11 0x560c93698a0e <unknown>
#12 0x560c9368ff8c <unknown>
#13 0x560c93660a62 <unknown>
#14 0x560c936b1538 <unknown>
#15 0x560c936b16dc <unknown>
#16 0x560c936c0b35 <unknown>
#17 0x7f8232ae6b43 <unknown>


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/src/BL/utils.py", line 418, in initializeBrowser
    driver = browsers.chrome(env)
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/src/BL/browsers.py", line 26, in chrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/docker/web-testing-wtai/WTAI-project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

I have ensured the file is at that path by doing nano `/usr/bin/chromedriver` and I get this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! [ -x /snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver ]; then
    echo "" >&2
    echo "Command '$0' requires the chromium snap to be installed." >&2
    echo "Please install it with:" >&2
    echo "" >&2
    echo "snap install chromium" >&2
    echo "" >&2
    exit 1
fi
exec /snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver "$@"
```

I really do not understand the reason why selenium is not able to find the chromedriver executable. What am I doing wrong? Alternatively, how could I avoid specifying the path, as I did before I got the exception? I started getting this exception when using my script in a new computer with the same selenium version ( 4.8.2 ) but higher chromium version (in the previous one I had 114.0.5735.90 and now 114.0.5735.198. If the chromedriver version missmatch is the problem, how could I change it using only command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `webdriver_manager` to directly download and launch the driver without providing the path.

You can install by using `webdriver_manager` by using `pip3 install webdriver_manager`

```py
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("Your URL")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I tried your solution but I now get " (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)". Do you have any idea of how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, `no chrome binary at /usr/bin/chromedriver`, it appears you may be mixing up the binary location (where Chrome is located) with the `chromedriver` location. These are not the same.

And your call to `webdriver.Chrome()` would no longer work due to recent changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

(Note that the first argument is no longer `executable_path`, but `options`.)

If you want to pass in an `executable_path`, you'll have to use the `service` arg now:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--auto-show-cursor')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

(Selenium now downloads `chromedriver` for you if it is not found on your PATH.)